# Add space between two text inside an options tag

Tags: html, browser, html-select

I need to display the following using select/options tag 
January       (1)
February      (2)
March         (3)
.
.
.
December      (12)

How to give space between the month and its number? I tried usng nbsp , emsp, ensp , thinsp but the space differs when I open it in Firefox and chrome. The space needs to be equal in both browsers.

How can I achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: "*The space needs to be equal in both browsers.*" - why? Are the site's users going to be so concerned about minor pixel-differences, or is this some form of pixel-perfect duplication as a requirement of your client? Either wway, I'm not sure that it matters enough to worry about.

Comment: Hi David, My requirement is very simple, just consider a table like structure which has all the months in one column and all their corresponding numbers in another column. If you just imagine this there will be equal spacing between the month and its numbers in an order. To achieve this form i tried putting &nbsp; , &thinsp; between the month and its number and made look aligned using chrome. But when i open the same using firefox, the numbers were not in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways to have the month names and the month numbers line up in two columns, as though they were table columns.

```
<select>
<option>--Choose Month--</option>
<option value="1">01 (January)</option>
<option value="2">02 (February)</option>
<option value="3">03 (March)</option>
<option value="4">04 (April)</option>
<option value="5">05 (May)</option>
<option value="6">06 (June)</option>
<option value="7">07 (July)</option>
<option value="8">08 (August)</option>
<option value="9">09 (September)</option>
<option value="10">10 (October)</option>
<option value="11">11 (November)</option>
<option value="12">12 (December)</option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select style="font-family: monospace">
<option>--Choose Month--</option>
<option value="1">January&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)</option>
<option value="2">February&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(2)</option>
<option value="3">March&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(3)</option>
<option value="4">April&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(4)</option>
<option value="5">May&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(5)</option>
<option value="6">June&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(6)</option>
<option value="7">July&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(7)</option>
<option value="8">August&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(8)</option>
<option value="9">September&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(9)</option>
<option value="10">October&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(10)</option>
<option value="11">November&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(11)</option>
<option value="12">December&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(12)</option>
</select>
```

The resulting dropdowns look like this, in Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari & Opera:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If `<option>January (1)</option>`, containing a normal space, has different spacing in different situations, this is caused by the use of different fonts. The width of a space varies by font. So you would need to set the font of the `option` element; it is safest to set that font on the `select` element too, since some browsers don’t let you style `option` elements directly, only via `select`.

For maximal compatibility, you would need to use a downloadable font with `@font-face`.

Answer (score -1):

Use & nbsp ; in the  tag between month name and number. You can use as many spaces as you want. Remove space between & and nbsp; in the code.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Use & nbsp, use many of it, until satisfied with the result